# How to find the shared value between two values in another column?

Tags: sql

I need to list supplier names of parts shipped by both S2 and S4. I have 3 tables named S, P, and SP but S and SP are the only ones I need.

SP table

```
sno | pno | 
s1    p1
s2    p1
s2    p2
s4    p2
s4    p4
s4    p5
```

S table

```
sno | sname 
S1    Smith
s2    Jones
s4    Clarke
```

I just have so far:

```
SELECT s.sname FROM s INNER JOIN sp ON s.sno = sp.sno
```

Comment: `p2` is supplied by both `s2` and `s4` so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: `p1` is supplied by both `s1` and `s2`, why not get `Smith` and `Jones`? Also, as `p2` is supplied by both `s2` and `s4`, why not get `Jones` and `Clarke`?

Comment: Yeah the question is a little confusing but that's what my assignment states. I have to list supplier name(s) of parts shipped by S2 and S4 only.

Comment: So your output should be `Jones` and `Clarke` because they are both suppliers of part `p2`.

Comment: @Smutje You should consider suppliers `S2` and `S4` only.

Comment: @felipeptcho Wow you are right. To be honest I have been up all night doing many assignments and I can barely make sense of anything

Comment: @nedst3r I think your output will always be that (or empty if they have no part in common).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
SELECT sname
FROM s WHERE sno IN (SELECT MAX(sno) FROM sp 
                    GROUP BY pno HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(sno)) > 1)
```

Comment: Are you considering only suppliers `S2` and `S4`?

Comment: According to question one pno shared in two sno and based on sample data it will return S2 and S4 for now but, other names also considered on big volume data.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it's not working on my end. I think I just need to have the names of s2 and s4 as my output but the question is confusing me that I'm not even sure what the output should be

Comment: Your questions is clear if it is not wrong  and Its giving exact result what you want ? but don't know what's wrong at your end. Anyway thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT s.sname FROM s
    INNER JOIN sp a ON a.sno = s.sno
    INNER JOIN sp b ON a.sno <> b.sno AND a.pno = b.pno
    WHERE a.sno IN ('s2', 's4') AND b.sno IN ('s2', 's4')
    GROUP BY s.sno;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to list supplier names of parts shipped by both S2 and S4

Parts shipped by both s2 and s4:

```
select pno
from sp
where sno in ('s2','s4')
group by pno
having count(distinct sno) = 2;
```

Suppliers shipping these parts:

```
select distinct sno
from sp
where pno in 
(
  select pno
  from sp
  where sno in ('s2','s4')
  group by pno
  having count(distinct sno) = 2
);
```

Complete query for supplier names for these suppliers:

```
select sname 
from s
where sno in
(
  select sno
  from sp
  where pno in 
  (
    select pno
    from sp
    where sno in ('s2','s4')
    group by pno
    having count(distinct sno) = 2
  )
);
```